# how to pass data by id form a laravel specific table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-7

please give me a solution with laravel query builder

```php
@php
$all_price = DB::table('tbl_productprice')
->get();
@endphp
                    
@foreach($all_price as $v_price)
<input type="hidden" name="price" value="{{$v_price->BuyingPrice}}">
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@php
$all_price = DB::table('tbl_productprice')
->get();
@endphp
```

```
@foreach($all_price as $v_price)
<input type="hidden" name="price" value="{{$v_price->BuyingPrice}}" data-id="{{$v_price->id}}">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$v_price->id}}">
@endforeach
```

or

```
@foreach($all_price as $v_price)
<input type="hidden" name="price" value="{{$v_price->BuyingPrice}}_{{$v_price->id}}">
@endforeach
```

or

```
{{ Form::hidden('data-id', $v_price->id) }}
{{ Form::hidden('data-price', $v_price->BuyingPrice) }}
```

Now on the Controller side, you will get it as:-

```
$request->input('data-id'); 
$request->input('data-id');
```